# Cannot add .onClick method to object in child component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm using React and jQuery. I have two components — an `Index` and a `Body`, which are children of the same `App` component.

I want to render an object of the `Index` with an .onClick function. However, the function needs `Body` to be rendered first.

Because I need to access an object in `Body`, I thought about adding the .onClick function to the object from `Index` right at the parent `App` component.

This is how I did it. Everything loads, but the element never gets the .onClick functionality. The console also doesn't print anything if I click the element.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Index ref="index"/>
                <Body ref="body"/>
            </div> );
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        function autoScroll (…) {
            const fp = findDOMNode(this.refs.body.refs.fullpage); // can only do this after rendering
            $(fp).fullpage.moveTo(…); // function to be called by object on Index
            console.log("clicked");
        }

        const lab = findDOMNode(this.refs.index.refs.lab)
        $(lab).onClick = function(){ this.autoScroll(…); };
    }
}
```

Comment: `onclick` handler will be called after component first mount anyway. I think you can define your autoScroll function outside of `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: I can, by adding an extra argument to autoScroll for the `fp` object. `fp=findDOMNode…` unfortunately can only be called after rendering, in `componentDidMount`. But either way, this still doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use jquery to set onclick handlers in react. Instead pass a function to Index via props and inside Index pass it along to the object that needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i'm gonna start by maybe suggesting staying away from JQuery in a React app mainly because it can get complicating when you have two things manipulating the DOM.

In React you usually define a class method for a `onClick` handler and pass it in the render method. Your on the right track!

```
class App extends React.Component {

  // This will be the function we will pass down as the onClick
  autoScroll = () => {
    const fp = findDOMNode(this.refs.body.refs.fullpage);
    $(fp).fullpage.moveTo(…);
    console.log("clicked");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Index handleClick={this.autoScroll} />
        <Body handleClick={this.autoScoll} />
      </div>
    );

  }
}


class Index extends React.Component {
  // You can access the click handler with the props object.
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.handleClick}>I am the index component</button>
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so so so much, it worked! I changed it to `onClick={() => this.props.handleClick}` so that `handleClick` wasn't fired during rendering.

Comment: And I do have to use jQuery and React on the same project, unfortunately.